# push notification firebase play custom sound in PWA

Tags: javascript, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am currently working on an PWA app and I have implement firebase Push Notification service into my app. I am receive notification on my phone but I am unable to set the custom alert sound that I want.
how play a sound when receive push notification.

Comment: did you get any response ?